# How to fill up a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following javascript:

```
    var SeatSection,
        firstClassSeats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        EconomySeats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    function check() {
        SeatSection = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
        if (SeatSection == 1) {
            firstClass();
        } else if (SeatSection == 2) {
            Economy();
        } else {
            Other();
        }
    }

    function firstClass() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
            if (firstClassSeats[i] == 0) {
                window.alert("been assigned to seat " + i);
                firstClassSeats[i] == 1;
                break;
            }
        };
    }
```

I have it so that when the number "1" is entered it will call the first class function. However, in the first class function I would like it so that it loops from 0 - 5 and if the first element in firstclassseats array is equal to 0 then book the seat. then it should change that element to equal 1 and check to see if the next element is equal to 0 and book that seat and so on. Can't figure out how to save the booked seats to the array and augment the count by 1 to go to the next firstclassseats array element.

Any advice?

Comment: Even basic code editor software does code formatting. Which code editor are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside you loop you are not assigning the value you're comparing it

```
firstClassSeats[i] == 1;
```

and it should be

```
firstClassSeats[i] = 1;
```

also when you loop you have written

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
```

this will increment i before getting into your loop and will skip the first array element, starting at [1], what you need is

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```